# Finding expected value school-level problem

Tags: probability

The problem is the following.

There are $n$ boxes with presents and $n$ people. The first chooses box and takes his present. The second doesn't know from which box the present is already taken by the first one so he chooses some box and gets his present if there is one and so on. How many presents will be left in the boxes (will not be taken)?  I guess that the correct question would be what is the expected value of the left in the box presents.

I have never learned any probability theory not even at school so I don't know what to do. But I googled the definitions and I know that probability translates into the language of measure theory.

So I guess I am asking to translate this into measure and integral language then I might be able to easily solve it.

Comment: This problem is somewhat similar to famous 'birthday' and 'hat check' (or 'envelope stuffing') problems.

Answer (score 5):

A box remains full iff it's never selected, which happens with probability $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n\approx\frac{1}{e}$. In particular, this is also the mean number of presents remaining in that box. Since means are additive even for dependent variables, the mean number of remaining presents is $n$ times this.

Comment: I understand why is probability equal to $(1- \frac{1}{n})^n $ by I don’t get what follows mostly because I don’t know the theory. Could you explicitly say what function (including domain and codomain) do we integrate?

Comment: @Vladislav You don't solve this with an integral; you just note each of the $n$ people has probability $1-1/n$ of not checking that box.

Comment: Nice answer (+1). In view OP's Comment, my answer gives a little more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_i= 0$ if the gift in the $i$th box (out of $n)$ is taken, otherwise, $X_i = 1.$
Thus $P(X_i = 1) = (1 - 1/n)^n$ and $E(X_i) = (1-1/n)^n.$ 
You seek $$E(X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n)\\ = E(X_1) + E(X_2) + \cdots + E(X_n)\\ = n(1-1/n)^n.$$

Simulation of a million runs with $n = 10$ boxes; at each run, `t` is the number of presents taken:

```
set.seed(1123)
m = 10^6;  n = 10
t = replicate(m, length(unique(sample(1:n, n, rep=T))))
mean(n-t)      # avg nr not taken
[1] 3.48815    # aprx 3.487
n*(1-1/n)^n
[1] 3.486784   # exact from formula
```

For $n = 100$ boxes the simulation gave $36.605$ and the formula gives
$36.603.$

---

*Note:* While it is true that $E(X_i) = (1 - 1/n)^n \approx 1/e$ for large $n,$
this limiting relationship is not of much use for finding the expected
number of unclaimed presents (to one decimal place), unless the number $n$ of boxes is quite large.

```
n = c(5, 10, 20, 50, 100);  r = (1-1/n)^n;  
ans=n*r;  aprx = n*exp(-1)
cbind(n,r,ans,aprx)
       n         r       ans      aprx
[1,]   5 0.3276800  1.638400  1.839397
[2,]  10 0.3486784  3.486784  3.678794
[3,]  20 0.3584859  7.169718  7.357589
[4,]  50 0.3641697 18.208484 18.393972
[5,] 100 0.3660323 36.603234 36.787944
```